# Can I do this with LESS?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I just started on LESS because of it's flexibility, and I ran into a problem. I want to do something like this:

```
.shadow-argument ( @type, @horizontal, @vertical, @blur, @color ) when ( @type = normal ) {
@argument = @horizontal @vertical @blur @color;
}
.shadow-argument ( @type, @horizontal, @vertical, @blur, @color ) when ( @type = inset ) {
@argument = @horizontal @vertical @blur @color inset;
}
```

And then pass the function to an argument like this:

```
@shadow-something: .shadow-argument(normal, 1px, 1px, 3px, #eeeeee);
```

Is it possible ? If not what would be the way around it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in place of the argument and [it will match the correct one](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions):

```
.shadow-argument(normal, @horizontal, @vertical, @blur, @color) {
  @argument = @horizontal @vertical @blur @color;
}

.shadow-argument(inset, @horizontal, @vertical, @blur, @color) {
  @argument = @horizontal @vertical @blur @color inset;
}
```

Comment: So it is possible to pass to `@arg` the function ? That's awesome, I fcking love LESS, I should have started a long time ago on it :)

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure what you mean there. Also the LESS site seems to dislike hashtags, so the link doesn't jump down to the right section. Just do a search on the page for "pattern".

Comment: I mean, I want to give the value of the function to an variable `@var`, the value of the function being what I have in the post.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't even notice that, sorry. Erm, that's not how mixins work, you, well *mix them in*—they don't return anything. I'm not sure how functions work in LESS either, as I primarily use Sass.

Comment: OK. So I cannot do that, :( . Is there a way around it and achieve what I need ? SAAS is almost the same as LESS.